# Passing linked list that consists of three structures to a function

Tags: c, list, structure

I know how create a linked list with two structures

To do so, I declare a structure that contains all the necessary data. It looks like this:

```
struct Data{
    int numb;
    int date;
}
```

Second structure represents a node that has a **head** (i.e. first element of the list) and a link to the next node.

```
struct llist{
    Data d;
    llist *next;
}
```

I wonder what if I wanted to add my **llist** to another structure that would represent a **list**.

```
struct mainList{
    llist l;
}
```

I know it may create some difficulties as I'm not quite sure how to pass **main list** to a function.

Here, I've tried to print linked list

```
void show(mainlist *ml){
    llist *u = ml->l;
    while(u){
        printf("Date: %s\t Name: %s\n",  u->d.dat, u->d.uname/* u->d.dat, u->d.uname*/);
        u=u->next;
    }
}
```

But got an error saying that "I cannot 'llist' to 'llist*' in initialization'
So, I'm clueless here... Any ideas?

Comment: What is the point of a `struct` with one member?

Comment: Well, I used it for demonstrating purposes. The main goal was to understand how to set up pointers to be able to carry out manipulations with linked lists. Due to answers bellow I now have a better understanding of this concept)

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues - however, one pertaining to the error you are referring is the line:

```
llist *u = ml->l;  /* I guess you mean struct llist *u = ml->l */
```

in `show` function. Here `u` is a `struct llist *`, but `ml->l` is a `struct llist` , but NOT a pointer to it. You need to change the `struct mainList` as:

```
struct mainList{
    struct llist *l;
}
```

So that `ml->l` is a `struct llist *`.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution below, your code snippet had some issues. pointed out in comments...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Data {
    int numb;
    int date;
};

struct llist {
    Data d;
    llist *next;
};

struct mainList{
    llist *l; /*should be a pointer as you are referencing it as a pointer*/
};

void show(mainList *ml){ /*should be mainList, your code snippet shows 'mainlist'*/
    llist *u = ml->l;
    while(u){
        printf("Date: %d\t Name: %d\n",  u->d.date, u->d.numb/* u->d.dat, u->d.uname*/); /*your code snippet was using unavailable members of the struct*/
        u=u->next;
    }
}

int main ()
{

    mainList ml;

    show(&ml);

    return 0;
}
```